# Listas comprimidas junto con numpy.arange

Tags: python, array, numpy

Necesito generar un vector de índices y por el momento lo estoy haciendo en tres fases:

- 1º Creo el vector de índices con np.arange
- 2º Recorro el vector y realizo el desplazamiento
- 3º Recorro nuevamente el vector cada "BS" para extraer la primera posición e introducirlo en el nuevo vector

El código que tengo por el momento es:

```
# Valores iniciales
BS = 16
rows_1 = o_h * o_w
rows_2 = rows_1 // BS
# Creo vector de índices mediante np.arange
cont_1 = np.arange(rows_1, dtype=np.int32)
# Array para las posiciones a extraer de cont_1
index_aux = np.arange(0, rows_2, BS)

result = np.arange(rows_2, dtype=np.int32)

# Se realiza el desplazamiento en la posición
# correspondiente: Cada "o_w" posiciones
for i in range(1, o_w):
    cont_1[i*o_w:(i+1)*o_w] += i*(k_w-1)

# Finalmente, extraigo solo las posiciones 
# correspondientes a cada BS    
result = cont_1[index_aux]
```

Cuando `o_w` es múltiplo de `BS` no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando no son múltiplos, esta es la forma que se me ocurre por el momento. Existe alguna forma mas eficiente  y limpia para realizar esto? Según el profiler de spyder, en mi computadora tarda en torno a `6.5 ms` para `o_h, o_w = 1024, 1024`